# Is it possible to access [contenthash] or [hash] or [chunkhash] inside JS scripts?

Tags: webpack

So, the issue is that I have lazy script and css loading and need to know exact filename that I want to load. But I want those names to be hashed. How can I know those hashes (any of them will work) after each rebuild inside my JS files?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is only available at build time. But you can use a webpack plugin to write a manifest file with the generated filenames. https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin

Comment: I understand that it's available at build time. But also those JS files are build with webpack, maybe it's possible to access hash through DefinePlugin or similar